# How to use COMMON_TREE_NODE_STREAM

Tags: gcc, antlr3

I'm following http://antlr3.org/api/C/buildrec.html tutorial.

It's my understanding that in order to remove/alter tokens before they are consumed by the parser I have to use none buffered stream COMMON_TREE_NODE_STREAM

In this view, how should i feed the parser ?

currently I use tstream=antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew(ANTLR3_SIZE_HINT,TOKENSOURCE(lxr));
to "feed" the parser.

Appreciate every advice

Answer (score 0):

No, the COMMON_TREE_NODE_STREAM is the source for a tree parser, not the normal parser. The ANTLR_TOKEN_STREAM is the input stream for that which has a default implementation in the C runtime known as [ANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_STREAM_struct](http://antlr3.org/api/C/struct_a_n_t_l_r3___c_o_m_m_o_n___t_o_k_e_n___s_t_r_e_a_m__struct.html). Look up its implementation to learn how to create your own token stream.

Comment: thanks Mike. I think COMMON_TOKEN_STREAM is buffered - which stream is unbuffered ? (my goal is to dynamically skip tokens based on flag toggled from within action in the grammar) If I'm right, it's too late to alter tokens in the buffered stream. Any hint is appreciated